# External function call Erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I'm trying to call a function (from an external module) in erlang. both beam files are located in the same directory.

```
 -module(drop2).
 -export([fall_velocity/1]).
 fall_velocity(Distance) -> math:sqrt(2 * 9.8 * Distance).
```

Then I'm calling

```
-module(ask).
-export([term/0]).
term() ->
Input = io:read("Enter {x,distance} ? >>"),
Term = element(2,Input),
drop2:fall_velocity(Term).
```

it gives the following error.I tested individual modules for errors. it is compiling with out any errors or warning.

```
Eshell V5.10.2  (abort with ^G)
1> ask:term().
Enter {x,distance} ? >>{test,10}.
** exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression
 in function  drop2:fall_velocity/1 (drop2.erl, line 3)
```

Not sure why it is throwing arithmetic expression error .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read the [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#read-2) to figure out that the result is `{ok, Term}`. You could try the `io:read/1` function in the console, then you'd see following:

```
1> io:read("Enter > ").
Enter > {test, 42}.
{ok,{test,42}}
2>
```

That means that you need to deconstruct the result of `io:read/1` differently, for example like this:

```
-module(ask).
-export([term/0]).
term() ->
   {ok, {_, Distance}} = io:read("Enter {x, distance} > "),
   drop2:fall_velocity(Distance).
```